# Exercise 4.4 in Eloquent Javascript -- startsWith() and .slice

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Exercise 4.4 in Eloquent JavaScript.

This is the problem:

> Write a function called startsWith that takes two arguments, both
>   strings. It returns true when the first argument starts with the
>   characters in the second argument, and false otherwise.

This is the solution I came up with:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErhKS/3/

```
function startsWith(string1, pattern) {
    if (string1.slice(0,4) === pattern.slice(0,4) {
    return true;
    }
}

console.log(startsWith("something", "somethingmore"));
```

I don't understand why I'm getting errors in console.log().

I do understand the book's solution, and why it's a good solution:

```
function startsWith(string, pattern) {
  return string.slice(0, pattern.length) == pattern;
}
```

I'm just wondering why my own badly written function is erroring out in the console and returning:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { .
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just forgetting a close-paren after pattern.slice(0,4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you haven't ended all your parentheses in your `if` statement.

```
function startsWith(string1, pattern) {
  if (string1.slice(0,4)) === pattern.slice(0,4) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is an updated example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/ErhKS/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
function startsWith(string1, pattern) {
        if (string1.slice(0,4) === pattern.slice(0,4) ){
            return true;
            }
    }

        console.log(startsWith("something", "somethingmore"));
```

You missed if closing parenthesis. http://jsfiddle.net/ErhKS/5/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing ')' in the if.

Despite the fact you've got an error, I think you can think about the string.indexOf ;)